# How to search multiple records while reorganizing this data

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following table which I am trying to reorganize using XLOOKUP

[image: Source table]

=XLOOKUP($H7&$L$4&N$5,$B$3:$B$15&$C$3:$C$15&$D$3:$D$15,$E$3:$E$15,"NF",0,1)

[image]

As XLOOKUP can only look at the first value it misses the second value, my table comes out wrong.

[image: How can I get the second table. I also want to make this task as automated as possible so that I can do this with different data on different days.]

How can I get the second table. I also want to make this task as automated as possible so that I can do this with different data on different days.

Comment: Where does Soiled 800008 = 115000 come from?  I can't see that number anywhere in your data table.  Also the 2, 10 & 50 on the first row - where does that come from?  I can see it jumbled in amongst other numbers in Type2, but using that would mean 800008 Re-issueable = 757003 is looking at Type2 = 500 not 50?

Comment: With your data in `A1:D14` this will kind of work:  `=XLOOKUP(80007 & "Re-issueable" & 2,$A$2:$A$14 & $B$2:$B$14 & $C$2:$C$14,$D$2:$D$14,0)`.  The constants can be updated to look at cell ranges - e.g. the unique Code can be returned using `UNIQUE(A2:A14)` and referenced in the first part of the XLOOKUP.

Comment: Seems like a pivot table would work.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Fixed it.

Comment: @gns100 How? I am looking for a one step solution which can be automated.

Comment: @Ankit I can't see how your proposal of creating headers, adding and filling formula is easier to automate than inserting a pivot table.

Comment: @MátéJuhász I am okay with pivot table. but I couldn't make it work. If you have a way, please tell. Also, the format will remain same, only the values will change, so this method works, only issue is it misses multiple results.

Comment: @Ankit, I posted an answer to show the pivot table way. If you want to use a formula, then it will require nesting of additional formulas, probably `IF` and `SUM`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the pivot table solution (Note to remove [soiled, 5] just use the filter):

[image]